# what is best way to get props in React / React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm really regarding props in React/React-Native. I have a parent view. In this view I'm getting the user data from a LocalStorage.['

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, View } from 'native-base';
import NutrionalToolbar from '../../components/NutrionalToolbar';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export default class LogsScreen extends Component {

state = {
    user: '',
}

componentWillMount() {
    this._bootstrapAsync();
}

_bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    this.setState({ user: JSON.parse(user) })
};

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <NutrionalToolbar user={this.state.user} />
        </Container>
    );
}
```

}

Now inside the NutrionalToolbar component I have this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'native-base';

class NutrionalToolbar extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this.props) // This renders an empty user object
}



render() {
    console.log(this.props) // This renders the user object with values
    return (
        <View>
        </View>
    );
}
}

export default NutrionalToolbar;
```

How can I get this.props values inside the constructor. I'm getting the values inside render method. Why isn't working inside the constructor?

Comment: When your `NutionalToolbar` is instantiated there is no `user`, you're still fetching. Why do you need it in the constructor? There are other lifecycle hooks you can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking into the [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle hook because, even if you could access the initial `user` prop in the `constructor`, you wouldn't be able to access updates to that prop in the `constructor`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'native-base';

class NutrionalToolbar extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.props) // This will always log the current props
  }

  render() {
    return (<View></View>);
  }

}

export default NutrionalToolbar;
```